# Apache is redirecting to a non-existant virtual host

Tags: php, apache, redirect, relative-path, virtualhost

Earlier today I tried installing the MyImouto image board software on my Apache server. I already have the full MediaWiki engine installed on port 80 (`localhost/wiki/`) and the MyImouto board installed in a virtual host on port 3000, running completely separate from the main web server.

After fiddling around a little, I made a mistake with a php-based upload on the main server and had to reinstall apache and php both, which I did, and upgraded to the latest versions (Apache 2.2.22 and PHP 5.4.0). I managed to get my setup up and running successfully, both with the port 3000 virtual host and without. And MediaWiki functions fine, except for one thing.

NOW when I type in `http://localhost/wiki/index.php` as I have always done in the past, something is redirecting it to `http://localhost:3000/wiki/index.php/Main_Page` and shifting it to the other virtual host, where there is no wiki at all. However `http://localhost/wiki/index.php/Main_Page` does work perfectly.

There's an `.htaccess` file in `localhost:3000` which I renamed to something else, but that doesn't seem to do the trick. I also tried clearing the browser cache as well as running a session_destroy via php. It didn't fix it.

I even turned off the second virtual host in Apache's httpd.conf, but it still redirects me which tells me that it is something in the main webserver. I did not touch the MediaWiki configuration or code during this entire time.

I also attempted accessing `http://localhost/phpMyAdmin` and THAT redirected me to `http://localhost:3000/phpMyAdmin/`, as well as `http://localhost/AdminTools` which does the same type of thing. `Httpd.conf` now no longer has any references at all to the virtual host `*:3000`.

However, my main index (`http://localhost/index.php`) has the following header redirect, which successfully lets it work even when `http://localhost` is typed into the address bar.

```
header("Location: index.php?content=main");
```

I tried disabling expires_module and headers_module in Apache, thinking there might be some weird caching issue due to that now-renamed .htaccess file. That did not help either. In addition, I checked my hosts file and there is nothing odd in there, nor am I proxying through anything (this -is- localhost after all).

Would appreciate any help in figuring out what's causing this and how to fix it.

---

- Windows XP SP3
- Enabled Modules in Apache:

  actions, alias, asis, auth_basic, authn_default, authn_file, authz_default, authz_groupfile, authz_host, authz_user, cgi, dir, env, expires, headers, include, isapi, log, mime, negotiation, rewrite, setenvif, php5
- Enabled extensions in PHP:

  curl, fileinfo, gd2, mbstring, exif, mysql, mysqli, openssl, pdo_mysql, sockets

Comment: You're more likely to get responses if you post your actual http.conf file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. After fiddling a little bit with .htaccess and Rewrite Rules (none of which did anything), I took a look inside my httpd.conf file again and found that I had typo'd my port-80 Virtual Host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin -myemail-@gmail.com
  ServerName -blahblah-.no-ip.org:3000
  DocumentRoot "C:/wwwroot/tfg"
  <Directory "C:/wwwroot/tfg">
    OptionsIndexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
    Deny from 186
    Deny from 187
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When in fact it should have been `ServerName -blahblah-.no-ip.org:80`.

Simple typos: always the ones that slip by the easiest.